# Dart Model for Flutter, dyanmic list

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Good Afternoon

I need assistance with the following JSON response and creating a correct dart model.

I have added every type but having a hard time with mapping dynamic to I guess dynamic list?

JSON response:

{
"status": "Ok",
"report": {
"35310": {
"id": "35310",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "131581",
"publish_date": "2021-10-07 17:42:09",
"title": "Scouting Starts Soon"
},
"35309": {
"id": "35309",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "171165",
"publish_date": "2021-10-07 12:25:27",
"title": "VOTE VOTE VOTE -Notice #21"
},
"35308": {
"id": "35308",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "171165",
"publish_date": "2021-10-07 12:15:31",
"title": "NT Manager Insight-Notice #20"
},
"35301": {
"id": "35301",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "171165",
"publish_date": "2021-10-05 08:05:17",
"title": "GET VOTING-Notice #19"
},
"35261": {
"id": "35261",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "171165",
"publish_date": "2021-09-25 14:30:01",
"title": "BR All Blacks-Notice #18"
},
"35259": {
"id": "35259",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "131581",
"publish_date": "2021-09-25 04:58:45",
"title": "World Cup Quarter-Final!"
},
"35227": {
"id": "35227",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "131581",
"publish_date": "2021-09-17 20:03:01",
"title": "S46 NZ Monday Friendlies"
},
"35219": {
"id": "35219",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "131581",
"publish_date": "2021-09-14 08:00:12",
"title": "World Cup Time!"
},
"35177": {
"id": "35177",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "171165",
"publish_date": "2021-08-22 20:03:35",
"title": "Best NZ manager-Opinion #17"
},
"35172": {
"id": "35172",
"country_iso": "NZ",
"authorid": "171165",
"publish_date": "2021-08-19 08:53:44",
"title": "Interim Journalist-Notice #16"
}
},
"brt": "2021-10-10T00:38:33+12:00",
"gameDate": {
"season": 46,
"round": 1,
"day": 7
}
}

```
GlobalNews globalNewsFromJson(String str) =>
    GlobalNews.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String globalNewsToJson(GlobalNews data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class GlobalNews {
  GlobalNews({
    required this.status,
    required this.report,
    required this.brt,
    required this.gameDate,
  });

  String status;
  List<Report> report;
  DateTime brt;
  GameDate gameDate;

  factory GlobalNews.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GlobalNews(
        status: json["status"],
        report: Map.from(json["report"])
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Report>(k, Report.fromJson(v))),
        brt: DateTime.parse(json["brt"]),
        gameDate: GameDate.fromJson(json["gameDate"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "report": Map.from(report)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
        "brt": brt.toIso8601String(),
        "gameDate": gameDate.toJson(),
      };
}

class GameDate {
  GameDate({
    required this.season,
    required this.round,
    required this.day,
  });

  int season;
  int round;
  int day;

  factory GameDate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GameDate(
        season: json["season"],
        round: json["round"],
        day: json["day"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "season": season,
        "round": round,
        "day": day,
      };
}

class Report {
  Report({
    required this.id,
    required this.countryIso,
    required this.authorid,
    required this.publishDate,
    required this.title,
  });

  String id;
  String countryIso;
  String authorid;
  DateTime publishDate;
  String title;

  factory Report.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Report(
        id: json["id"],
        countryIso: json["country_iso"],
        authorid: json["authorid"],
        publishDate: DateTime.parse(json["publish_date"]),
        title: json["title"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "country_iso": countryIso,
        "authorid": authorid,
        "publish_date": publishDate.toIso8601String(),
        "title": title,
      };
}
```

Thank you for the help any help or information that could be provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to change your response like following. `report` field contains an array of report objects. If you format like this you can use some code generation tool like [this](https://jsontodart.com/) to generate you model class easily. Small catch - most tools are not null safe :( Please comment if you found one

```
{
    "status": "Ok",
    "report": [
        {
            "id": "35172",
            "country_iso": "NZ",
            "authorid": "171165",
            "publish_date": "2021-08-19 08:53:44",
            "title": "Interim Journalist-Notice #16"
        },
        {
            "id": "35177",
            "country_iso": "NZ",
            "authorid": "171165",
            "publish_date": "2021-08-22 20:03:35",
            "title": "Best NZ manager-Opinion #17"
        }
    ],
    "brt": "2021-10-10T00:38:33+12:00",
    "gameDate": {
        "season": 46,
        "round": 1,
        "day": 7
    }
}
```

generated model code from the tool

```
class GlobalNews {
  String status;
  List<Report> report;
  String brt;
  GameDate gameDate;

  GlobalNews({this.status, this.report, this.brt, this.gameDate});

  GlobalNews.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['report'] != null) {
      report = new List<Report>();
      json['report'].forEach((v) {
        report.add(new Report.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    brt = json['brt'];
    gameDate = json['gameDate'] != null
        ? new GameDate.fromJson(json['gameDate'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.report != null) {
      data['report'] = this.report.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['brt'] = this.brt;
    if (this.gameDate != null) {
      data['gameDate'] = this.gameDate.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Report {
  String id;
  String countryIso;
  String authorid;
  String publishDate;
  String title;

  Report(
      {this.id, this.countryIso, this.authorid, this.publishDate, this.title});

  Report.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    countryIso = json['country_iso'];
    authorid = json['authorid'];
    publishDate = json['publish_date'];
    title = json['title'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['country_iso'] = this.countryIso;
    data['authorid'] = this.authorid;
    data['publish_date'] = this.publishDate;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    return data;
  }
}

class GameDate {
  int season;
  int round;
  int day;

  GameDate({this.season, this.round, this.day});

  GameDate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    season = json['season'];
    round = json['round'];
    day = json['day'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['season'] = this.season;
    data['round'] = this.round;
    data['day'] = this.day;
    return data;
  }
}
```

if you can't change your JSON change the `GlobalNews.fromJson` code to following

```
GlobalNews.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['report'] != null) {
      report = [];
      Map<String, dynamic> reportMap = json['report'];
      reportMap.forEach((id, data) {
        report.add(new Report.fromJson(data));
      });
    }
    brt = json['brt'];
    gameDate =
        json['gameDate'] != null ? GameDate.fromJson(json['gameDate']) : null;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's exactly what I would have wanted, but unfortunately, It's not my API. Sadness

Comment: small tweak will do the job. answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You can try `json_serializable` package. Its a Dart Build System builders for handling JSON. Once you use this package, you don't need to write that huge code manually. This package will auto generates for you.